# SQL put quotes around everything after equals

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL string I want to put quotes around everything after equals.

Current: `@Condition = N'Sev = 300 OR EVC = 102 AND SRC = 380P064`

After: `@Condition = N'Sev = '300' OR EVC = '102' AND SRC = '380P064'`

Is there a quick fix to get what I want? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Could you explain more? Didn't quite understand..

Comment: So I am passing a parameter in a dynamic SQL query and one or the parameters in @Condition I want to put the values after equal inside quotes. Eg Sev = 100 will become SEV = '100' or Cond =Hi becomes Cond ='Hi'

Comment: Use sp_executesql stored proc to execute dynamic sql. This allows you to pass parameters properly. The way you're exposing yourself to sql injection. Also the code will be harder to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

Ashamed I didn't see this before

```
Declare @Condition nvarchar(max) = N'Sev = 300 OR EVC = 102 AND SRC = 380P064 AND XXX = HELLO'

Set @Condition = Replace(Replace(Replace(@Condition,'= ','= '''),' OR ',''' OR '),' AND ',''' AND ')+''''

Select @Condition
```

Returns

```
Sev = '300' OR EVC = '102' AND SRC = '380P064' AND XXX = 'HELLO'
```

Or if you want the original

```
Set @Condition=@Condition+''''
Select @Condition = Replace(@Condition,MapFrom,MapTo)
 From  (values ('= ','= ''')
              ,(' OR ',''' OR ')
              ,(' AND ',''' AND ')
       ) A (MapFrom,MapTo) 


Select @Condition
```

Comment: How will I use this if say for example i had COND = Hi and i want it to be COND ='HI'

Comment: @Krishneil Just saw your comment up top.  Let me give it another shot

Comment: I feel like you are going around the problem instead of through it  @Krishneil

Comment: @scsimon I suspect he is building some dynamic SQL, my guess it is UI driven

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understood your question but I'll give it a try...

If you wanna use ' to signify a string, you need to escape it in your first N'Sev. like this

```
@Condition = N/'Sev = '300' OR EVC = '102' AND SRC = '380P064'
```

You can also consider to use " instead

```
@Condition = N'Sev = "300" OR EVC = "102" AND SRC = "380P064"
```

Comment: the Sev = 300 is just an example it can be anything and the length of the string can be as long as 1000 chars

Comment: Hmm.. see my edit.. I can't quite understand.. 1000 chars...?

Comment: Do you try to get it to do that automaticly?

Comment: Yes I am trying to get it to do that automaticly

Comment: Well.. Where do you get the data to check your sql? Because, you'll basicly need it to know if you're gonna check a string or a integer.